# Dynamic typing and return values in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, dynamic-typing

I have run into a very strange behaviour I can’t make sense of. I have a `Texture` class with `contentWidth` property of type `int`. This class is wrapped in a `Image` class that has a `width` property of type `int`. The `width` of an `Image` is computed simply as the `contentWidth` of the underlying texture:

```
- (int) width
{
    return texture.contentWidth;
}
```

Now the `Image` is used by a `Button` class (by composition, not inheritance) that wants to read the image size:

```
// image is of type ‘id’
int width = [image width];
int height = [image height];
```

The problem is that the `height` variable gets set just fine, whereas the `width` variable contains `NaN` (–2147483648). I have checked the dimensions – they are about 200×100 or so, nowhere near the `int` limit. Also the Xcode debugger tooltip shows both properties in the `Texture` correctly, only after the width gets through the two accessors the number gets garbled. The objects are not freed. What am I missing?

---

*Update:* I have expanded the accessor in the `Image` class to see where the problem originates:

```
- (int) width
{
    const int w = texture.contentWidth;
    return w;
}
```

Now when I break on the first line, the `w` gets set correctly. I step over, the execution returns to the calling function:

```
- (void) foo
{
    int bar = [image width];
}
```

…and now the `bar` contains `NaN`.

---

*Update:* Mhm, got it:

```
int foo = [image width]; // image is id, returns NaN
int bar = [(Image*) image width]; // correct value
```

The `image` is declared as `id`, which is the point here. Could somebody explain this? I have got a feeling I am not calling the right `width` method, but what exactly is going on here? I always type my variables as strictly as possible, but here the `id` type is handy. I had no idea it could result in such a bug.

Comment: Have you implemented a contentWidth accessor in your Texture class?

Comment: What's the difference between the width and height accessors? How is the height accessor implemented in Image?

Comment: @Tim: There is no difference, the ‘height’ accessor looks exactly the same. Except for the names, of course :)

Comment: @Perspx: Yes, otherwise the compiler would complain in the ‘width’ accessor of the Image class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh well. If you are interested in why this situation happens, see the Objective-C Programming Guide, chapter 8, [Return and Argument Types](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocStaticBehavior.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH16-TPXREF161):

> In general, methods in different
>   classes that have the same selector
>   (the same name) must also share the
>   same return and argument types. This
>   constraint is imposed by the compiler
>   to allow dynamic binding. Because the
>   class of a message receiver (and
>   therefore class-specific details about
>   the method it’s asked to perform),
>   can’t be known at compile time, the
>   compiler must treat all methods with
>   the same name alike. When it prepares
>   information on method return and
>   argument types for the runtime system,
>   it creates just one method description
>   for each method selector.
>
> However, when a message is sent to a
>   statically typed object, the class of
>   the receiver is known by the compiler.
>   The compiler has access to
>   class-specific information about the
>   methods. Therefore, the message is
>   freed from the restrictions on its
>   return and argument types.

Here’s a [bug report](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=36283) in the GCC bugzilla (and a corresponding [blog post](http://jongampark.wordpress.com/2008/05/20/dynamic-typing-and-returned-value-with-objective-c/)). The behaviour is not a bug, but it isn’t very friendly either, because the compiler does not warn you (at least not with the default warning settings).

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't your accessor be:

```
- (int) width
{
    return [texture contentWidth];
}
```

Is texture an instance variable? If it is, did you make super to initialize it in the init method or your wrapper class?

Comment: The two are equivalent - Objective-C will convert the dot-accessor syntax to a passed message during compilation.

Comment: Its a good idea anyway from a "good practice" standpoint... 
In that case, I would make sure your instance is properly initialized.

Comment: I have just overriden the ‘description’ method on the Texture class and logged the dimensions there, they are fine.