# Objective-C Type Inference

Tags: objective-c, types, inference

Okay, I have a feeling that you guys'll be able to quickly point out why I'm so confused about this, but I have a question as to why the following does NOT result in a compiler error or warning:

```
NSString * intValue = [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"int = %i", [ [ self.selectedObject valueForKey:name ] integerValue ] ];
```

`selectedObject` is an `NSObject`, and `name` happens to be the name of a `@property` of type `int`.

What perplexes me is why the compiler is perfectly willing to assume that the return result of `[ self.selectedObject valueForKey:name ]` is of type `NSNumber *` (without typecasting it) in order to chain the message with a call to `integerValue`.

Obviously, KVC wraps up non-object "number" types into `NSNumber`, but there's no way for the compiler to know that `-valueForKey:` will return an `NSNumber *` in this particular case.

Why doesn't this result in a compiler warning along the lines of "`id` may not respond to '`-integerValue`'"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I hope I got it right: This is because `id` is “special”. Objects of the `id` type can be sent any message you want, there is no checking done by the compiler and everything will be checked in runtime. Or, in other words, the `id` type is the “dynamic typing” part of Objective-C, whereas all the other types (like `NSObject`) are the “static typing” part.

This way you can choose where you want to use static typing, and where you want to use dynamic typing. It is perfectly legal to do something like this:

```
id str1 = @"Hello";
id str2 = [str1 stringByAppendingString:@", world"];
```

But usually you type the strings “tightly” as `NSString`s, because you get the convenience of compile-time static type check, and only resort to dynamic typing where the static one would get in the way, like in the `valueForKey` situation.

Comment: Thanks! I had a feeling it had to do with `id` being a privileged type in Objective-C. :) My tendency is to ALWAYS tightly type things whenever possibly, so I guess I never encountered this seemingly strange behavior. Guess that makes `id` both powerful and dangerous. I wonder if it's better to typecast to give the compiler some context when dealing with `id`, or if it's perfectly fine to leave that out if you're positive of what `id` will become (as was the case in my example).

Comment: The rule of the thumb is: “Static Typing Where Possible, Dynamic Typing When Needed.” (You can Google that to get further info.) In this case I would not typecast, it would only make the expression harder to read. Sometimes you have to typecast to help the compiler choose the right method – see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113270.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've encountered some nasty little bugs as a result of method naming that happens to "conflict" with existing SDK method names. Thought the compiler was going crazy on me. :) And yes, I'm totally a proponent of the “Static Typing Where Possible, Dynamic Typing When Needed” philosophy. Now if only Objective-C would add support for typed collections... Seemingly more often than not, I know what my collections are going to store.

Answer (score 9):

Time is passed and we have better type inference now thanks to the `__auto_type` 
available since Xcode 8. So now you can do

```
#define let __auto_type const
#define var __auto_type

let a = @[@"pew pew"];
var b = 2;
b = a; //compiler warning "Incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'int' from 'NSArray *__strong const'"
```

and [much more](https://github.com/Tricertops/Typed)

In fact, I liked this so much so I made this as a pod for convenience.

```
pod 'SwiftyObjC'
```