# List of known Xcode bugs / gotchas

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4

Is there such a list?

I'm relatively new to iOS development and I'm think it would be great to study a list of most well-known compiler bugs or gotchas.

EDIT:
Today I spent too much time to understand what's going on with code like this:

in *.h

```
@interface I : NSObject {
    ..
    NSSMutableArray* var; // typo, should be m_var;
}

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSMutableArray* var;
```

in *.m

```
@implementation I

@synthesize var = m_var; // no warnings or anything

-(id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        // no warning or errors
        m_var = [NSMutableArray new];
    }
    return self;
}
```

And I think it's time to learn some of the well-known Objective-C idiosyncrasies.

Comment: How do you know that `m_var` is always nil. As best I can tell, `var` should always be nil, since you aren't using it for anything.

Comment: @kubi sorry, you are right. debugger window in Xcode 4 tells me that var is nil.

Comment: There is no bug in the code you’ve posted. You’ve told the compiler to synthesise an instance variable called `m_var`, and so it did.

Comment: @Bavarious documentation states "use the @synthesize directive to tell the compiler *to create the accessor methods*". so I think I told compiler to do just that and not to create an instance variable. Btw, my question is really not about this specific issue.

Comment: The documentation also says that ‘instance variables are synthesized as needed.’ In your particular example, it is needed since `m_var` hasn’t been declared. It’d be nice to have a warning, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple’s list of bugs is internal to Apple.

I think that [Open Radar](http://openradar.appspot.com) is the closest thing you’ll get to a public list of bugs related to Apple products, including Xcode. It is maintained by the community — users are encouraged to post to Open Radar the bug reports that have been submitted to Apple.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has its [own bug tracker](http://bugreport.apple.com), but you can only see you own reports (!?)

Your best bet is then [openradar](http://openradar.appspot.com/)... Which is limited.

**EDIT**: About your supposed Xcode Bug, even if that's not the question.

Remember that `@synthesize` is just *syntactic* sugar that will generate code at compilation.
My guess is that your var property is conflicting with your var member.

I would not say that's a bug, more a predictable issue that could be integrated in clang static analysis.

Anyway, that's obviously a code typo, a human error, tools are just there to help us, or we would write assembly bytecode directly :)

Answer (score 1):

The golden rule of debugging: *it’s not compiler’s fault*. Some behaviours are a bit strange, like the one you show here, but they are by design. As for the “bug” in question, the compiler can synthesize instance variables for you, without them having to be declared:

```
@interface Foo {}
@property(assign) float bar;
@end

@implementation Foo
@synthesize bar;

- (void) somewhere { bar = 1; }

@end
```

This is convenient and allows you to move private interfaces into the implementation file. Coming back to your example, you now have two instances variables, `var` and `m_var`, the second one acting as a storage for the `var` property. It’s not exactly something to be happy about, but it makes perfect sense. (Could there be a warning that you have an instance variable that doesn’t act as a store for a property with the same name?)

As this kind of behaviour is mostly by design, you won’t find it in the Radar and would have to look for a list of common Objective-C gotchas. ([This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113270) is another interesting situation.)

Comment: The `var` instance variable is `nil` because you did not assign it a value. If I understand your code correctly, `self.var` will be non-nil.

Comment: Just checked: `self.var` is `nil` right after `m_var = [NSMutableArray new];`