# NSNumber claims to be NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am getting the warning `Comparison of distinct pointer types ('NSString *' and 'NSNumber *')` in this line of code:

```
if(beacon.beaconIdentifier == self.identifier) {
  // do something
}
```

Both should contain an NSNumber. The object `beacon` is a CLBeacon. `self.identifier` is a NSNumber. Other possibly relevant code:

CLBeacon category

```
@interface CLBeacon ();
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *beaconIdentifier;
@end

static char const *const MyBeaconIdentifier = "MyBeaconIdentifier";

....

- (CLBeacon *)initWithJSON:(NSDictionary *)json {
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    ...
    self.beaconIdentifier = json[@"id"];
  }
  return self;
}

- (void) setBeaconIdentifier:(NSNumber *)beaconIdentifier {
  objc_setAssociatedObject(self, MyBeaconIdentifier, beaconIdentifier, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
}

- (NSNumber *)beaconIdentifier {
   return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, MyBeaconIdentifier);
}
```

`json[@"id"]` always only contains numbers. Besides the warning, everything runs as it should. What is causing my problem and what could possibly solve it?

Thanks to a couple great responses, I managed to solve the warning. Still, I would like to know what caused it, if that is possible.

`beacon.beaconIdentifier.class` logs `_NSCFNumber`, just as `self.identifier` does.

Comment: **Don't** use `==` to check objects for equality in Objective-C. Use `isEqual:` instead.

Comment: NSLog(@"json[@"id"] class: %@", NSStringFromClass([json[@"id"] class]))...

Comment: I have encountered many situations, when I thought it would be `NSNumber` and it wasn't. Is it possible for you, to save it as, let's say, an integer (`json[@"id"].intValue`) and then compare it like this - `self.beaconIdentifier == self.identifier.intValue`? Or is the number too large?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are using pointer equality (“do these pointers point to the same address?”) where you want to use object equality (“are the objects pointed to by these pointers considered equal?”). Simply call `-isEqual:` instead of using `==` to fix this. [Comparing using `==` could work for `NSNumber`s since they are tagged pointers, but you shouldn’t do it anyway.]

Second, if the *compiler* complains of mismatched types, `beaconIdentifier` and `self.identifier` can’t really both be declared as `NSNumber`s, there has to be an `NSString` somewhere.

Comment: While using `==` will give the wrong answer, that doesn't seem to solve the compiler warning.  It thinks those pointers are of different types, doesn't it?

Comment: I think it should solve the compiler warning, since it’s legal to compare two objects of different classes? But you’re right that it doesn’t necessarily make sense, for example an `NSNumber` and an `NSString` containing the same number would not be considered equal.

Comment: Well it's not legal to compare pointers to different types.  I think the OP is lying when he says `self.identifier` is `NSNumber`.

Comment: You’re right – if it’s the compiler who complains about distinct pointer types, one of the properties has to be declared as a string.

Comment: @zoul They both log as an NSNumber and are both declared as an NSNumber. `-isEqual` solves the warning, though, and the program runs as intended. Thank you.

Comment: @J.Constantine Maybe a name collision? Are you sure there aren't any superclasses that declare `identifier` as a `NSString*`?

Comment: @Sulthan The warning is about `beacon.beaconIdentifier`. And I am sure that is not the case. Both are actually called differently in the code. I used generic names for privacy reasons here.

Comment: @J.Constantine Isn't `beacon` declared as `id` by any chance? E.g. a result of array indexing?

Comment: @Sulthan Not that I know of. I'm getting them using: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager:didRangeBeacons:inRegion:

Answer (score 1):

You say `json[@"id"]` contains a number, but that is not known at compile-time. Hence the warning. Its only at run-time that it will be identified as `NSNumber` by the compiler.

To check equality of `NSNumber`, try this code

```
if([beacon.beaconIdentifier isEqualToNumber:self.identifier]) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: @zoul: It is mentioned in the question: **self.identifier is a NSNumber**

Comment: Sorry, deleted my comment since I’m not sure which one of the properties is a string. Yes, it’s mentioned in the post, but the compiler complains one of those is a string and the other a number. And the compiler is usually right.

Comment: The odd thing is that when I make `self.identifier` an NSString, it complains that `beacon.beaconIdentifier` is an NSNumber.

Comment: That’s interesting. Could you reproduce the behaviour on a smaller code sample or upload the project somewhere?

Comment: @zoul I'm afraid that will not be easy, as there's a pretty big API behind the project, and I'm not allowed to give out any code. I could look into that after work time. The `-equals` method fixed the warnings for now.

Comment: It does, because from the compiler’s perspective it’s perfectly legal to check object equality between two objects of a different class. And as they are actually two numbers at runtime, the code works. But if the compiler thinks one of them is a string, that’s still a problem. I had a [great time with a similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113270) once.